# Virtual hosts & symbolic links, why can't I set DocumentRoot to a symbolic link?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, symbolic-link

I have recently setup Capistrano on my server and it works great.
I changed my virtual hosts to point to the symbolic link created by Capistrano.
My virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my_app.com/current
    ServerName my_app.com
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart my apache server using `sudo service httpd restart`, I get the error:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/my_app.com/current] does not exist
```

The `current` directory definitely exists. When I set the vhost to point to `.../my_app.com/`, it works and shows the default apache page, the problem is this symbolic link to `current` (which is updated as I deploy applications using capistrano).

I am using a Amazon ec2 instance, apache 2.2 (LAMP).

**so basically, how do I point a virtual host to a symbolic link?**

---

**Update**
The output of `ls-l`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   57 Aug 28 22:40 current -> /var/www/html/my_app.com/releases/20120828223437
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug 28 22:40 releases
drwxrwxr-x 6 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug 28 16:01 shared
```

In my `httpd.conf`(comments stripped out):

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My Error Logs:

```
[Wed Aug 29 00:04:39 2012] [error] [client 87.194.51.136] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/my_app.com/current
[Wed Aug 29 00:04:40 2012] [error] [client 128.30.52.73] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/my_app.com/current
[Wed Aug 29 00:04:40 2012] [error] [client 87.194.51.136] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/my_app.com/current, referer: http://mydomain.com/
```

The ouput of `ls -l` for `/var/www/html/my_app.com/releases/20120828223949`.

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug 28 22:39 20120828223949
```

When I run the command `ls -l /var/www/html/my_app.com/current/`

```
ls: cannot access /var/www/html/my_app.com/current/: No such file or directory
```

Looks like a dead symlink... How do i fix this?

Comment: Can you provide us with the output of `ls -l /var/www/html/my_app.com/`? At any rate, you should probably know that using symlinks in this way can [lead to problems](http://www.mikebrittain.com/blog/2009/05/12/case-against-using-symlinks-for-code-promotion/).

Comment: This can be permission on one of the sub-folders of the destination of the link, as symlink is always rwxrwxrwx, so you need to grant your apache access to it.

Comment: What are your logs showing?  You can set an errorlog in the virtual host `ErrorLog /home/httpd/logs/error_log`

Comment: This may or may not work but try disabling SELinux  `setenforce 0` This command will temporarily turn it off

Comment: Does the apache user (I assume apache runs as user ec2-user) have execute permissions on `/var/www/html/my_app.com/releases/20120828223437` and all parent directories?

Comment: I've updated the post to include the dir permissions for the releases dir.

Comment: Unless you've redeployed between edits, your problem is a dead symlink. `current` is pointing at a directory ending `223437`, and your `releases` directory contains a directory ending `223949`.

Comment: Does `ls -l /var/www/html/my_app.com/current/` (note trailing slash) return what-you-expect?

Comment: No, I get the error ls: cannot access /var/www/html/my_app.com/current/: No such file or directory.

Comment: When I try and symlink it again `ln -sf /var/www/html/my_app.com/current /var/www/html/my_app.com/releases/20120828223949/`, Nothing is outputted but the symlink still points to the old dir.

Comment: You've got the arguments to `ln` in the wrong order, it should be "from" then "to" (like `cp`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As-per-my-comment and your follow-up it looks like your `current` symlink doesn't point to a valid target; remove it and re-add it:

```
$ rm -f /var/www/html/my_app.com/current
$ ln -s /var/www/html/my_app.com/{releases/20120828223949,current}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran `rm -f /var/www/html/my_app.com/current && ln -s /var/www/html/my_app.com/releases/20120828223949 /var/www/html/my_app.com/current` and it worked!